# How to fix NoSuchElementException when doing app automation using Appium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, appium, appium-android, browserstack

This is a script on app automation that I am executing on BrowserStack.

Here is my code:

```py
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.mobileby import MobileBy
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

userName = "xxxxx"
accessKey = "yyyyy"

desired_caps = {
    "build": "Python android login",
    "device": "Samsung Galaxy S8 Plus",
    "app": "bs://e761bd35add7e1da33f6a4c480bf91a96dcd3382",
    'autoAcceptAlerts': 'true',
    'name' :'App test2'
}

try:

    driver = webdriver.Remote("https://" + userName + ":" + accessKey + "@hub- 
    cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub", desired_caps)
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//oj-button-text[contains(text(),'Agree')]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("oj-button-1401427062-1|text").click()
    print("Click completed on agree buton")

except:
    raise
```

Here are the properties:

[image]

| Button | Properties |
| --- | --- |
| Name | SPAN |
| Type | 1 |
| Id | oj-button-1401427062-1 |
| Class | oj-button-text |
| Text | Agree |
| X | 854.6563110351562 |
| Y | 2079.0 |
| W | 207.34375762939453 |
| H | 41.000000953674316 |
| BgColor | rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) |
| Visibility | visible |
| Display | inline |
| Overflow | hidden |
| Position | static |
| CssSelector | #oj-button-1401427062-1 |
| Xpath | //span[@id="oj-button-1401427062-1 |

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It’s most likely a span and not a oj-button tag which is given in the xpath.

Answer (score 0):

As per the element properties, it's a *`<span>`* element with *class* as ***oj-button-text*** and *text* as ***Agree***.

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***Agree*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'Agree')]").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='oj-button-text' and contains(., 'Agree')]").click()
```